# how to get max rows from 2 transactional tables. MySQL

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have two mysql transactional tables and and two lookup tables. I want to select max(id) from each of the transactional tables, combine the results with lookup tables and combine into one row. I seem unable to find solutions so far. Here is my tables. Stocks and Prices are transactional while Vehicle and Models are lookup tables.

**Vehicles table**

```
 id  name
 1   Toyota
 2   Suzuki
```

**Models table**

```
 id  vehicle_id  name
 1   1           Corolla
 2   2           Swift
 3   1           Prado
 4   2           Vitara
```

**Stocks table**

```
 id  vehicle_id  model_id  qty
 1   1           1         50
 2   2           2         77
 3   1           1         40
 4   2           2         30
```

**Prices table**

```
 id  vehicle_id  model_id  price
 1   1           1         500
 2   2           2         777
 3   1           1         600
 4   2           2         1000
```

Expected results

```
 id  vehicle_id  model_id  qty price  vname  mname
 1   1           1         40  600    Toyota Corolla
 2   2           2         30  1000   Suzuki Swift
```

Here is what I've tried among countless trials

```
select s.*, b.name vehicle, m.name model, p.price
                                  from stocks s, vehicles b, models m, prices p
                                  where s.id in (select max(id) id from stocks
                                  where s.vehicle_id = b.id and s.model_id = m.id  and s.vehicle_id = p.vehicle_id and s.model_id = p.model_id
                                  group by vehicle_id, model_id)
                                  order by id;
```

Running the above query doesn't give me what I want and it crushes the PC. I have to restart. How can I achieve the expected outcome?

Comment: Please update your question tags. Microsoft `sql-server` conflicts with `mysql` and the `ruby-on-rails` tag seems unrelated to the actual question.

Comment: @Sander, tags removed. I am a Rails so the reason I added Ruby on Rails is maybe someone could achieve this the Ruby way,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 8 you can use window functions and common table expressions for latest(based on maximum id per vehicle and model group) prices and qty for vehicle and models

```
with pricescte as (select *,
  rank() over (partition by vehicle_id,model_id order by id desc) AS price_rank
from prices),
  stockcte as (select *,
    rank() over (partition by vehicle_id,model_id order by id desc) AS stock_rank
  from stocks)

select v.id,
  v.name,
  m.id as model_id,
  m.name,
  s.qty,
  p.price
from vehicles v
join models m on v.id = m.vehicle_id
join stockcte s on v.id = s.vehicle_id 
    and m.id = s.model_id
join pricescte p on v.id = p.vehicle_id 
    and m.id = p.model_id
where s.stock_rank = 1
    and p.price_rank = 1
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nrqDiakaeYE6dngHszNv1o/0)

If you are not on latest version of MySQL < 8 you could use a query like

```
select v.id,
  v.name,
  m.id as model_id,
  m.name,
  s.qty,
  p.price
from vehicles v
join models m on v.id = m.vehicle_id
join (
    select *
    from stocks st
    where id = (
        select max(id)
        from stocks
        where st.vehicle_id =vehicle_id
          and st.model_id = model_id
    )
) s 
    on v.id = s.vehicle_id 
        and m.id = s.model_id
join (
    select *
    from prices pr
    where id = (
        select max(id)
        from prices
        where pr.vehicle_id =vehicle_id
          and pr.model_id = model_id
    )
) p on v.id = p.vehicle_id 
    and m.id = p.model_id
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hokpnvDQq5CzdxXkkRshbT/0)

Comment: I am on MySQL 5 and your solution works very well. Thanks a lot. By the way, which literature/book is covering this?

Comment: @JohnMilo its all from SO university :),apart from this you can visit the greatest n per group tag for mysql questions for group wise maximum there are variety of approaches used